# Error en sumatorio

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de números l=[a(1),...,a(n)], y quiero calcular el sumatorio de i=1 hasta n de i*a(i). Pero me sale que "i++;" es un error de sintaxis , haciendo el código pensaba que estaba bien , a qué se debe el error? Habría otra manera de ponerlo?

```
def b1(l):
i=1;
sumatorio=0;
suma=0;
for x in l:
    suma = i*x;
    sumatorio+=suma;
    i++;
return sumatorio;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta `i++` no existe es `i+=1` 
puedes hacerlo así también para una mayor eficiencia:

```
def b2(*l):
    return sum([ (i+1)*j for i,j in enumerate(l)])
```

explicación:

1. Recibimos el arreglo el `b2(*l)` el `*` hace referencia a que se
   recibirá un arreglo de datos.
2. El método `sum()` suma los valores de un arreglo.
3. El método `enumerate` enumera las posiciones de un arreglo en
   índice-valor, donde`i` es el índice y `j` es el valor.
4. Debido a que el índice empieza en cero le sumamos 1.

> el metodo que utilizo se conoce como `shorthand`

Comment: Muy buena respuesta , muchas gracias. Es más bonito y elegante por listas por comprensión como lo haces.

Answer (score 2):

El `++` **no existe** en python.

En su lugar, basta con hacer

```
i += 1;
```